# ModelState validation in Web Api when default formatter is servicestack

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialization, deserialization, servicestack

I have WEB.API controller which use attribute for modelstate validation, when I use default serializer of WEB API every thing works fine, but when I change it to servicestack required attribute for bool values and EnumDataType(typeof(VehicleType)) does not work. I mean It shows that model state is valid regarding It's not, I configured servicestack this way:
In Owin startup:

```
private void ConfigureServicestack(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Formatters.RemoveAt(0);
    config.Formatters.Insert(0, new ServiceStackTesxtFormatter());
}
```

and this class for servicestack:

```
public class ServiceStackTextFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public ServiceStackTextFormatter()
    {
        JsConfig.ConvertObjectTypesIntoStringDictionary = true;
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

        SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true));
        SupportedEncodings.Add(new UnicodeEncoding(bigEndian: false, byteOrderMark: true, throwOnInvalidBytes: true));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        return true;
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        var task = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStream(type, readStream));
        return task;
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonSerializer.SerializeToStream(value, type, writeStream));
        return task;
    }
}
```

my controller input is like this:

```
        public class PostRequest 
    {

//this is custom attribute and works fine
        [Number]
        public string VehicleId{ get; set; }

//It works fine for string value
        [Required]
        public string CompanyWebSiteAddress{ get; set; }

//when I insert invalid vehicletype modelstate.isvalid is true

        [EnumDataType(typeof(VehicleType))]
        public VehicleType VehicleType{ get; set; }

//for this bool value when I dont send IsOwner modelstate.Isvalid is true also
        [Required]
        public bool IsOwner { get; set; }
}
```

The Odd issue is when I remove ConfigureServicestack from my application startup every thing works fine, I thought maybe If one of Properties is null or is not provided by client servicestack desalinize it as default value for example for IsOwner set it like:"IsOwner":false, but I don't know If it's correct or how can  I turn off this feature

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, I dont know If there is a better way but by mark bool value nullable it works fine for bool values, this way:

```
public bool? IsOwner { get; set; }
```